# Windows 10 icons in Cordova config.xml

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-cli

I'm building my sencha touch app for windows 10 using cordova.
For iOS and Android [the cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/it/6.0.0/config_ref/images.html) explains very well how to configure the various icons and splashscreens.
But for windows the example shows very few icons, I've tried to configure them as in the example, but when I open the windows 10 built solution with visual studio, I see that all the icons are the default cordova ones, not the ones that I've configured.

I've added in my config.xml these lines

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="../resources/splashscreen/wp8/SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" height="1280"/>
    <icon src="../resources/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
    <!-- tile image -->
    <icon src="../resources/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="159" height="159" />
</platform>

<platform name="windows8">
    <splash src="../resources/splashscreen/windows8/SplashScreenImage.png" width="620" height="300"/>

    <icon src="../resources/icons/windows8/logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="../resources/icons/windows8/smalllogo.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="../resources/icons/windows8/storelogo.png" width="50" height="50" />
</platform>
```

But in visual studio I see these icons, and all are taken from the cordova default icon, the one with the "droid":

[image: App Icons]

Is there a way to configure the Windows 10 Icons in the config.xml?
In the cordova documentation I can't find anything about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using Visual Studio to build your app or are you using the cloud-based service by Adobe/Phonegap?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I'm using visual stidio

Comment: This is not for *Phonegap Build* *Phonegap Build* is a cloud-based build service by Adobe/Phonegap. This FAQ should also help. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: ever figure this out? The new Visual Studio TACO doesn't have options for image assets and editing the config.xml file doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You add this in config.xml for the Windows platform icons:

```
<platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/windows/storelogo.png" target="StoreLogo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/smalllogo.png" target="Square30x30Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square44x44Logo.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square70x70Logo.png" target="Square70x70Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square71x71Logo.png" target="Square71x71Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" target="Square150x150Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Square310x310Logo.png" target="Square310x310Logo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/Wide310x150Logo.png" target="Wide310x150Logo" />
</platform>
```

You place your custom icons at res/windows folder.

When you build the app, it will use these icons.

Also note that in your code you used platform name="windows8" and it should be "windows".